# "Item . not found" with ttk.Treeview().insert()

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, treeview

I'm trying to insert items in a tkinter treeview with five columns. I'm using this line of code:

```
self.resultsTable.insert(parent=self.parent, index='end', values=['1','2','3','4','5'])
```

However, the interpreter shows the following:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gigi\Desktop\me\projects\PyMusic\test\threaded_test.py", line 166, in searchMusic
    self.showResults()
  File "C:\Users\gigi\Desktop\me\projects\PyMusic\test\threaded_test.py", line 111, in showResults
    self.resultsTable.insert(parent=self.parent, index='end', values=['1','2','3','4','5']) # values=song['details']
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 1337, in insert
    res = self.tk.call(self._w, "insert", parent, index, *opts)
_tkinter.TclError: Item . not found
```

I searched a lot on the web for a solution, but I couldn't find one. Is there anyone experienced with tkinter who can help me?

Comment: what is `self.parent`? Is it an id of a previously added item?

Comment: @BryanOakley self.parent is the master/root level window. I misunderstood the meaning of that 'parent' keyword argument in the insert() method. I thought it referred to the parent widget of the treeview. I corrected the line of code accordingly, by replacing parent=self.parent with parent='', in order to add a new independent item (= a new row).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your `self.parent` represents the root window, which has a string representation of ".". The tree is telling you that it doesn't have any items in the tree with an id of `"."`.

The first argument to `insert` is *not* a widget. It should be either the empty string -- which represents the id of the root item *in the tree* -- or the id of a previously inserted item.